# JDBC driver para Oracle 11.2 y Java 17

Tags: oracle-11g, jdbc

Estoy desarrollando un backend en Spring Boot el cual debe conectarse a una base de datos Oracle 11.2 vía `thin` y `oci`.

Intento encontrar el driver correcto para Java 8, 11 y 17.

La [documentación oficial](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) de Oracle no es muy clara y presta a confusión, al menos para mi. En la [guía de Oracle para Developer's](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-00FE03D7-48D6-4DA5-A3A0-8768D2936AB8), existe una tabla de referencia para ayudarnos a seleccionar, pero, ninguna indica soporte para JDK 17.

En [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc) para el `com.oracle.database.jdbc` tampoco existe ninguna que indique JDK 17. Incluso, si entro al ojdbc8, sale un mensaje indicando que el artefacto ha sido movido a ojdbc10 y pasa lo mismo en otros casos, escenario que me causa confusión también.

En otros hilos en la comunidad, hay preguntas parecidas pero solo para JDK7 y 8, ninguna para 11 y 17.

Cualquier consejo para la selección sería de gran ayudan. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hola. ¿Acaso no es el primero en la tabla que se muestra en este [enlace](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html)?

Comment: @A.Cedano el primero llamado `ojdbc11`, según el título de esa sección, solo es para Oracle 23, 21, 19, 18 y 12.2. No se menciona 11.2

Comment: Revisa [este artículo](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#JJDBC20000). Para versiones modernas de Java no necesitas cargar el controlador explícitamente. Debería funcionar si tienes correctamente instalado el controlador más reciente. Al menos es lo que yo interpreto.

Comment: Me baso sobre todo en este párrafo del enlace antes referido: *If you are using JSE 6 and later, then there is no need to explicitly load the JDBC driver. This means that the Java run-time loads the driver when needed and you need not include Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver") or new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver() in your code. But if you are using J2SE 5.0, then you need to load the JDBC driver explicitly.*

Comment: Si es un desarrollo nuevo, no deberías hacerlo con versiones obsoletas.

Comment: Sin pensarlo mucho probaría para JDK8,11 y 15 el ojdbc8.jar de JDBC21.x y para JDK17 el ojdbc11.jar de la misma versión.